# Android create tabbed activity

Tags: android, android-activity, swipe, tabbed

I'm very new in android developing. I'm want to do an application that contains two screen and I can select them by swipe the screen. It is that ? And if yes, Why it doesn't let me run this application ? I am creating this application and when I try to run it(With no changes or something) it show's error :

```
your project contains errors please fix them android eclipse
```

Any one know why ? Thank's.

Comment: Post your code that u tried.

Comment: I have been edit my question, please take a look.